# Ansible lineine file with regex is adding new line when it shouldn't

Tags: python, regex, ansible, python-2.x

I currently have this file for configuring nagios nrpe:

```
/etc/xinetd.d/nrpe:

# default: on
# description: NRPE (Nagios Remote Plugin Executor)
service nrpe
{
        flags           = REUSE
        socket_type     = stream    
        port            = 5666    
        wait            = no
        user            = nagios
        group           = nagios
        server          = /usr/local/nagios/bin/nrpe
        server_args     = -c /usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg --inetd
        log_on_failure  += USERID
        disable         = no
        only_from       = 192.168.1.1 
}
```

(Note that the only_from is a fake IP, but I'm attempting to write the ansible command to work regardless of the IP provided)

I'm attempting to use ansible's [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html) module to allow me to add another variable to the line starting with `only_from`

Currently I have the following:

```
---
- name: Edit Existing | Edit xinetd.d/nrpe file
  vars: 
    - nagios_ip: 194.54.46.12
  lineinefile:
    backrefs: yes
    backup: yes
    dest: /etc/xinetd.d/nrpe
    line: 'only_from = \1 {{ nagios_ip }}'
    regexp: '\s*only_from\s+=\s*(((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\s*)*)'
```

This works, mostly. I get the line changed, but the `{{ nagios_ip }}` variable is sent to a newline and the file ends up looking like so with the new IP address on a new line, as opposed to on the same line:

```
# default: on
# description: NRPE (Nagios Remote Plugin Executor)
service nrpe
{
        flags           = REUSE
        socket_type     = stream    
        port            = 5666    
        wait            = no
        user            = nagios
        group           = nagios
        server          = /usr/local/nagios/bin/nrpe
        server_args     = -c /usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg --inetd
        log_on_failure  += USERID
        disable         = no
        only_from       = 192.168.1.1 
127.0.0.1
}
```

Because ansible/lineinfile uses python's regex engine I tested it in plain python:

```
>>> s = '      only_from        = 127.0.0.1'
>>> r = '\s*only_from\s+=\s*(((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\s*)*)'
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r,s).group(1)
'127.0.0.1'
>>> re.match(r,s).group(1) + ' 192.168.1.1'
'127.0.0.1 192.168.1.1'
>>>
```

And it works as expected. How do I get rid of the new line that ansible is putting in?

Comment: The string is most likely `192.168.1.1\n`. See if there is any way to strip new lines and append it to the overall end of your string. You probably still want a newline at the end of all this but not in the middle. Something like `192.168.1.1 127.0.0.1\n` I'm assuming?

Comment: @idjaw you're correct in that I do want the new line at the end. Do you have any thoughts on what is adding the `\n` to the backref (my regex, ansible, python)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not played with this ansible module yet. I would have to experiment as much as you at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are matching the newline too. Don't include the newline in your match. This should work:

```
regexp: '\s*only_from\s+=\s*((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\s*'
```

Now why did your plain python work? Because you conveniently omitted the newline in your test. Your test string should be:

```
s = '      only_from        = 127.0.0.1\n'
```

Your corrected example is:

```
>>> s = '      only_from        = 127.0.0.1\n'
>>> r = '\s*only_from\s+=\s*(((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\s*)*)'
>>> import re
>>> print re.match(r,s).group(1) + ' 192.168.1.1'
127.0.0.1
 192.168.1.1
>>> r = '\s*only_from\s+=\s*((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\s*'
>>> print re.match(r,s).group(1) + ' 192.168.1.1'
127.0.0.1 192.168.1.1
>>>
```